# BeautifulSoup extract data within a div of divs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I want to extract data from a ul and this ul is inside div and so on.I have done it with lxml but now i want to try it with beautiful soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = "https://linkedin.com/company/1005"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find_all('div', class_="basic-info-description")
print div
```

[image]

Comment: any special reason for wanting to use bs4? in my opinion `lxml` is better then bs4 in most respects...

Comment: first you are using wrong class `ul` inside `basic-info-about` second find this div and then use `findChildren()` to get all children loop over them and then check `tag.name=='ul'` then you have this element do what you want with it

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for ana in soup.findAll('ul'):
  if ana.parent.name == 'div':
     #ana is the ul with a div parent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use find(All) again on bs objects that you have found like:

```
ul = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'basic-info-about'}).find('ul')
```

Disadvantage of above code is that it will raise an error if the first div is not in the html code. Better would be:

```
divs = soup.findAll(''div', attrs={'class':'basic-info-about'}')
for div in divs:
    ul = div.find('ul')
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.   You just need to swap the single quotes for double quotes that wrap the statement in the `findAll` expression.